# Script for deleting multiline blocks

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to remove duplicate if blocks from multiple files like if block inside returnString() is present in many other files :

```
/**
 *
 *
 *Some text
 *
 */
    private String returnString() {
        if (containsString()) {
            System.out.println("Random text");
            System.out.println("Random text");
        }

    System.out.println("Random text");
    }
    Some text
    Some text
```

I have stored this data in one file, i want to delete whole if block from all files using script. So final output should be:

```
/**
     *
     *
     *Some text
     *
     */
        private String returnString() {

        System.out.println("Random text");
        }
        Some text
        Some text
```

I dont have any previous experience with scripts but i have tried sed and able to delete some lines but not complete block. Kindly take a look if someone can help in this.

Comment: I find your question and example to be confusing.

Comment: Ok what is confusing here?? could you tell me so that i can explain more?

Comment: A small case of sample data, and the **required output from that data** reduce the ambiguity possible in verbal descriptions. Good luck.

Comment: Do you know which if blocks are duplicates? or you want a script to automatically find all duplicated if blocks and then delete?

Comment: updated question with required output, @Xorg yes i know the duplicate if blocks just want to delete that.

Comment: This question is off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a Java to Bash translation service.

Comment: @CodeGnome: mkb asked for help to delete some lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
 sed -i '/if .* {/,/}/d' file
```

Comment: @mkb please accept this as the questions solution if this solved your issue.

Comment: can you explain this "if .* {/,/}" ? :)

Comment: @Xorg The use of `,` between two `//` is a range operator which instructs `sed` to `d` (delete) those lines.

Comment: @jaypal singh..thank you..I am familiar with /.../,/.../ but this is a little tricky...how does sed use this to find all duplicated blocks?....just a thought

Comment: @Xorg It basically flip flops. The first occurrence of pattern flips (triggers the delete) until the matching end block is seen. The cycle repeats. If the end block is never found then every thing gets deleted. You can read more about it [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-29)

Comment: You should state that this will fail when there are nested `if` statements in the code or if the `{` is on a different line to the `if` or if there are various combinations of strings inside comments or .... so it's ONLY for use on code structured precisely as shown in the sample and with no potential false matches (e.g. a comment with a `}` in it) anywhere else in the files.